How can I access and modify a boolean attribute in edit mode?
Re Manually setting custom attributes per edge / vertex / etc
TLDR : In edit mode, the regular interface to access and edit attributes, mesh.attributes["MyAttribute"].data yields an empty sequence.
Fortunately, one can access the attributes through the edit mode bmesh. layer = bm.verts.layers.float.get("MyAttribute") Unfortunately, AFAIK the only supported data types through this interface are color, deform, float, float_color, float_vector, int, shape, skin and string. Source
I'm trying to access a boolean attribute. How can I do that ?
This begs the question for other supported attributes like byte color, 2D vector, 8-bit integer, 2D integer vector and Quaternion.


Coincidentally I am developing a similar add-on. Can't I just use the temporary change to object mode?
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269330/how-to-get-seams-as-an-edge-property-in-geometry-nodes

@mml This is indeed a solution. But for performance reason this is not possible for me. This will be queried in a panel and run several dozen times per seconds. I need to stay in edit mode. Going in and out of edit mode when your mesh is extremely dense can take several seconds up to several minutes. Cheers

I see. This is certainly not a smart way to do it. It seems that attribute editing will be available in the future, but it has not been realized yet.Cheers
